# Achieving desired standard deviation and mean by tweaking last element of iterable

Tags: python, math, statistics, mean, standard-deviation

Let's say I have a python list implementation such as

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> lst = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
>>> np.std(lst)
0.81649658092772603
>>> np.mean(lst)
0.0
```

Thus, the standard deviation of above iterable is **0.8164** and mean is **0.0**. Now let's say I have an incoming variable **0.5** which I would like to append to this list.

```
>>> incoming_variable = 0.5
>>> lst.append(incoming_variable)
>>> print(lst)
[-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5]
>>>
```

Now the mean and standard deviation have obviously changed

```
>>> np.std(lst)
0.73950997288745202
>>> np.mean(lst)
0.125
>>>
```

What I want is a method to tweak that ***incoming variable*** value such that even after appending to the list, the standard deviation and mean remains **0.8164** and **0.0** respectively.

**Note I am only allowed to change the value of the incoming variable and not the initial values in the list.**

Comment: To keep the mean the same the incoming variable must be the mean; this will decrease the standard deviation

Comment: As the previous comment states, what you ask is not possible with one added value--you ask to preserve two statistics, which means two degrees of freedom, but you insist on using only one new value. It could be done by adding *two* particular values. Will that suffice? However, this is not really a programming problem, but rather one in mathematics or in statistics.

Comment: @Rory Okay so how could it be done with two values?

Comment: Add the two values `np.mean(lst) + np.std(lst)` and `np.mean(lst) - np.std(lst)`. If this were the Mathematics Stack Exchange site I would elaborate. Note this is true for the population standard deviation, which is what you are using. The sample standard deviation would be different.